# Set<UITouch> has no member "location"

Tags: swift3, uiviewcontroller, member, uitouch

Part of a project that I am working on requires me to make an object be moved using touch. I'm currently running Swift 3.1 and Xcode 8.3.3. The 7th line gives me errors saying:

> Value of type `'Set<UITouch>'` has no member '`location`'

but I have looked up the documentation and it is a member. Is there some workaround? I only need to move the image based on touch and drag.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var thumbstickLocation = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100)

@IBOutlet weak var Thumbstick: UIButton!

override func touchesBegan(_ touches:Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let lastTouch : UITouch! = touches.first! as UITouch
    thumbstickLocation = touches.location(in: self.view)
    Thumbstick.center = thumbstickLocation

}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let lastTouch : UITouch! = touches.first! as UITouch
    thumbstickLocation = lastTouch.location(in: self.view)
    Thumbstick.center = thumbstickLocation
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler error is correct, `Set<UITouch>` has no member `location`. `UITouch` has property `location`.

What you actually need to write is `thumbstickLocation = lastTouch.location(in: self.view)` to move an object to where the touches began. You can also make your code more concise by writing the body of both functions in a single line.

In general, you should not use force unwrapping of optionals, but with these two functions, you can be sure that the `touches` set will have exactly one element (unless you set the view's `isMultipleTouchEnabled` property to `true`, in which case it will have more than one element), so `touches.first!` will never fail.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var thumbstickLocation = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100)

    @IBOutlet weak var Thumbstick: UIButton!

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches:Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        Thumbstick.center = touches.first!.location(in: self.view) 
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        Thumbstick.center = touches.first!.location(in: self.view)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`location` is indeed **not** a member of `Set<UITouch>`. You should access a `UITouch` element of the set to access it.

```
thumbstickLocation = touches.first!.location(in: self.view)
```

...but it's better to access it safely by using `if let` or `guard let`:

```
if let lastTouch = touches.first {
    thumbstickLocation = lastTouch.location(in: self.view)
    Thumbstick.center = thumbstickLocation
}
```